# Get Drawable resource from inside DefaultHandler

Tags: android, resources, drawable

I have the following code that works on my main Activity but I have an extended DefaultHandler class and want to be able to access some resources.

How do I get the following to work?

```
Drawable newMarker = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.generic2r);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could reference the activity context with MyActivity.this, to produce:

```
Drawable newMarker = MyActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.generic2r);
```

As long as you make sure that you only need your Handler from this specific activity.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the context as a parameter to Your handler.

Comment: Is there not an easy way of grabbing the global context or the resource?

Answer (score 0):

create an object of context and assign the main activity context to this object in main activity with the static specifier and access that object wherever you want